# How do I get one over the other with fixed elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar with

```
position: fixed;
float: right;
top: 40px;
right: 0;
z-index: 999;
```

And I have a dropdown menu with

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
display: none;
right: 80px;
margin-top: 20px;
```

The menu get showed with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").click(function () {
        $('ul:first', this).toggle();
    })
});
```

Now my sidebar gets displayed over my dropdown menu so you can't actually see it (I know it works because I removed the sidebar to see that it works) but how do I do so the dropdown menu will be displayed over the sidebar?

EDIT: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/RRqQ7/2/) of the issue

Comment: Just as a note, you don't need both `$(document).ready(function() ...` and the functionally identical `$(function() ...`.

Comment: Note: position:fixed does not need float:right, Also, instead of margin-top: 20px; specify the correct top property of your dropdown menu. Rgds,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `header nav { }`, add z-index: 99999;